# split file extension from an array

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the extension found in every file name in my array.

I have

```
files = ['file.tsv', 'file2.tsv', 'file3.tsv']
```

and want the output to be

```
files = ['file', 'file2', 'file3']
```

How do I perform this function on an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably want a list comprehension using your existing list:

```
import os
no_extensions = [os.path.splitext(file_name)[0] for file_name in files]
```

You should use `os.path.splitext` rather than `file_name.split('.')` because it will also work if your file names have a period in their middle (e.g. `"file.partial.dat"` will fail with `file_name.split('.')`)

Answer (score 0):

```
print str(files).replace(".tsv","")
```

probably isnt what your teacher wants but it will look about right ;P

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'\.')

['.'.join(pat.split(k)[:-1]) for k in files]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general way of doing it whatever the extension.

```
fileNames = [s.split('.')[0] for s in files]
```

It creates a new list and leaves your original one unchanged.

EDIT :

If you have names with dots in it (like file.tsv.zip), there's still a way to do it without no import:

```
fileNames = ['.'.join(s.split('.')[:-1]) for s in files]
```

And if you want to also support files with NO extension, then better use this one:

```
fileNames = [s if s.find('.')==-1 else '.'.join(s.split('.')[:-1]) for s in files]
```

(Okay it's getting a bit dirty though :P)

So the last one gives:

```
>> files = ['file.tsv', 'file2.tsv.zip', 'file3']
>> fileNames
    ['file', 'file2.tsv', 'file3']
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do...

```
Files = [n.split()[0] for n in files]
```